# How to write a python-for-android recipe for a package in a local directory and not a zip file url?

Tags: buildozer, python-for-android

I have

```
buildozer.spec
recipes/
  myrecipe/
    __init__.py
mypackage/
  setup.py
  code.py
```

But when I try to write a recipe with a `file://` URL as seen when googling this issue, I get an error `Exception: Given path is neither a file nor a directory: /home/user/project/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/mypackage/mypackage` (not the mypackage twice).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is an `IncludedFilesBehaviour` mixin just for this, just give it a relative path with `src_filename`:

```
from pythonforandroid.recipe import IncludedFilesBehaviour, CppCompiledComponentsPythonRecipe
import os
import sys

class MyRecipe(IncludedFilesBehaviour, CppCompiledComponentsPythonRecipe):
    version = 'stable'
    src_filename = "../../../phase-engine"
    name = 'phase-engine'

    depends = ['setuptools']

    call_hostpython_via_targetpython = False
    install_in_hostpython = True

    def get_recipe_env(self, arch):
        env = super().get_recipe_env(arch)
        env['LDFLAGS'] += ' -lc++_shared'
        return env

recipe = MyRecipe()
```